# Junit5 @BeforeEach doesn't get executed/seen in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, junit5

Running Junit5 tests (localhost) on Jenkins works but BeforeEach, AfterEach hooks do not fire. Surprisingly, when I run those in intelliJ IDE referencing the same path/directory which Jenkins consumes, the hooks execute.

Unit test class sample:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
 @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("BeforeEach");
    }
```

pom.xml junit part:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

I don't get any errors, warnings when running on Jenkins, it just gets skipped.
Inserting the `@BeforeEach` logic inside the actual `@Test` but obviously I don't want that.

Am using maven to execute the tests:
`mvn test -Dtest=unittest.partner.SampleTests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various stuff this worked:
inserting `maven-surefire-plugin`inside inside `pom.xml`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```